# Which Ubuntu version to choose

Tags: 32-bit, versions, compatibility, system-requirements, distro-recommendation

Actually I wanted to ask u all that which Ubuntu flavour should I choose??
I have a 2gigs ram 32bit lappy.
I want to learn Linux with Ubuntu
And want to choose a performance beast flavour of GOAT Ubuntu.

Kindly help guys...

Waiting for ur kind reply.

Remember.
I need good performance

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 32-bit version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Comment: I have and test *flavors* of Ubuntu including on 32-bit/i386 devices, but can tell you you've provided insufficient details to provide any meaningful answer to your question. Out of the box, in my testing Lubuntu 18.04 LTS (using GTK2) is lightest & fastest, HOWEVER it loses some lightness when GTK3 or Qt5 apps are used on it... Xubuntu is second lightest & fastest, as XFCE hadn't completed their move to GTK3 at 18.04's release, but it was part way there... You must consider the apps you intend using (if you plan using Qt apps - I'd very much consider KDE though LXQt was faster for 18.10/19.04

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the part about "GOAT Ubuntu".

Nevertheless, as far as I know the lightest Ubuntu flavor is **Lubuntu**: it's really optimized to run on weaker hardware.

Watch out, there seem to be two Lubuntu websites. The one linked from the [Ubuntu official flavours page](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) is `lubuntu.me`. (I don't know what's up with `lubuntu.net`.)

With that out of the way, there are 32-bit variants on the download page: "18.04.5 desktop" and "18.04 alternate":

https://lubuntu.me/downloads/